Grohe Veletto tap disassembly
Help opening a Grohe tap
Hello,
How do I open the nozzle end of this Grohe Veletto tap to clean it out?
After six years, there’s some build-up, and I think it’s making the spray button stick such that it kicks back and forth between stream and spray (and makes an awful noise).
My plumbing keys are too small to go over the face, nor do they seem to fit the notch pattern, as the outer ring has only four indents that look like contact points for a key.
Maybe the top end where it plugs into the braided line could be a wiser side to approach. Thank you.
I’m sorry I can’t include photos. That is technologically beyond me.

You may want to post a pic of the business end.
